# How to add prop validations to get rid of the linting error?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, lint

giving the code below, how can I get rid of the linting error:

Linting Error:

```
renderFirstForm is missing in props validation
productHero is missing in props validation
```

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { LandingPage } from '@myapp/myapp-ui';
import {
  Experiment,
  Variant,
} from '../classes';


const landingPageExperiment = new Experiment({
  name: 'landingPageExperiment',
  version: 3,
});


const fluidDarkAnimated = new Variant({
  name: 'fluidDarkAnimated',
  enhancer: () => ({
    renderJumbotron: ({ renderFirstForm }) => (
      <LandingPage.Jumbotron.FluidDarkAnimated
        renderFirstForm={renderFirstForm}
      />
    ),
    productHero: (
      <LandingPage.ProductHero.WithVideo />
    ),
    ordering: ({
      productHero,
    }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {productHero}
      </React.Fragment>
    ),
  }),
});

const twoColumn = new Variant({
  name: 'twoColumn',
  enhancer: () => ({
    renderJumbotron: ({ renderFirstForm }) => (
      <LandingPage.Jumbotron.TwoColumns
        renderFirstForm={renderFirstForm}
      />
    ),
    productHero: (
      <LandingPage.ProductHero.ListOnly />
    ),

    ordering: ({
      productHero,
    }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {productHero}
      </React.Fragment>
    ),
  }),
});

landingPageExperiment.addVariants([
  fluidDarkAnimated,
  twoColumn,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

PropTypes are just a validation and they effect only in development (in most setups). Most production build setups strip off PropTypes for optimization.

To address your problem, you have a tricky Component definition in your example.

`renderFirstForm` is a prop used in `LandingPage.Jumbotron.FluidDarkAnimated` component. But I'm quite not sure in which component `productHero` is used.

In any case, PropTypes are static properties of a class. So they can be added anywhere in your code. You can even add PropTypes for another component in a different file.

To get rid of

```
renderFirstForm is missing in props validation
```

You need to add this snippet somewhere in your code (preferably right next to the component definition)

```
LandingPage.Jumbotron.FluidDarkAnimated.propTypes = {
  renderFirstForm: PropTypes.bool // I'm guessing it's a boolean by its name
}
```

To get rid of

```
productHero is missing in props validation
```

Find out in which component, `productHero` is used as prop and add this snippet

```
ThatComponentName.propTypes = {
  productHero: PropTypes.object // generic type
}
```

You can choose your PropType from [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)

Comment: Can you add what's in myapp-ui file?

Comment: You can try adding these prop type definitions in myapp-ui file

Answer (score 0):

try twoColumn.propTypes = { productHero: PropTypes.element.isRequired };

source of reference https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html